# Algolia: define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings

Tags: python, django, algolia

Requested setting ALGOLIA, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I've tried:

1 export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=Website.settings (I checked to be `Website.settings` when I turned on the server(`python manage.py runserver`))

2 to specify PYTHONPATH

3 I've also checked the API KEYS to be valid and have the right installed apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`

```py
INSTALLED_APPS=[
  ...
  "algoliasearch_django",
  ...
]

ALGOLIA = {
    'APPLICATION_ID': ' ',
    'API_KEY': ' '
}
```

- chatgpt

And still couldn't figure it out.

TO REPLICATE THE PROBLEM: SIMPLE DJANGO PROJECT + [ALGOLIA](https://www.algolia.com/doc/framework-integration/django/setup/?client=python)

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.